# WebRequest Does Not Contain A Definition For Create

Tags: c#

I ran a console application yesterday to send and receive web request and web response and it works fine. Today I'm testing the same method on my form application and I get the error WebRequest Does Not Contain A Definition For Create. All my imports are the same. It's a bit strange and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the code to my console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebrequestCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter sw;
            sw = File.AppendText("c:\\Temp\\webresponse.txt");
            //Create a Web-Request to an URL
            HttpWebRequest HWR_Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.hitta.se/ericsson/företag_och_personer");

            //Send Web-Request and receive a Web-Response
            HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)HWR_Request.GetResponse();

            //Translate data from the Web-Response to a string
            Stream S_DataStream = HWR_Response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader SR_DataStream = new StreamReader(S_DataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string s_ResponseString = SR_DataStream.ReadToEnd();
            S_DataStream.Close();
            sw.WriteLine(s_ResponseString);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load("c:\\Temp\\webresponse.txt");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

And this is my form application that cannot accept my Create:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace PhoneFind
{
    class WebRequest
    {
        private String url { get; set; }
        private String searchEngine { get; set; }
        HttpWebRequest HWR_Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.hitta.se/ericsson/företag_och_personer");
        public WebRequest(String url, String searchEngine)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.searchEngine = searchEngine;
        }

        // sends a request to the search engine 
        public String sendRequest(String url, String searchEngine)
        {
            switch (searchEngine){
                case "hitta":
                    //Create a Web-Request to a URL

                    //Send Web-Request and receive a Web-Response
                    HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)HWR_Request.GetResponse();

                    //Translate data from the Web-Response to a string
                    Stream S_DataStream = HWR_Response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader SR_DataStream = new StreamReader(S_DataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    string s_ResponseString = SR_DataStream.ReadToEnd();
                    S_DataStream.Close();
                    break;
            }
            return "";

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use System.Net.WebRequest in a class named WebRequest - I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain about ambiguous names.  In your form program try `HttpWebRequest HWR_Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.hitta.se/ericsson/foretag_och_personer");`

Comment: @Tim, there is no ambiguity since his class gets precedence because the code is inside this class.

Comment: @AmiramKorach - Thanks.  Wasn't sure if there would be an ambiguity or not.  But that still explains his error, as his class doesn't contain a definition for `Create`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. post it as an answer so I can select you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form application, your class is named `WebRequest`, so the compiler is looking for a `Create` method in that class, rather that `System.Net.WebRequest` class.  In order to resolve this, fully qualify the `WebRequest` in System.Net:

```
HttpWebRequest HWR_Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.hitta.se/ericsson/företag_och_personer");
```

Thanks to Amiram for clarifying that it wasn't an ambiguous name conflict as I originally thought it might be.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because you are targeting `.net framework` less than `4.5`, to solve this problem just change the `target framework` to `4.5` from the `project properties application tab`, then rebuild the project.